# Pidgin indicator missing

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, applications, notifications

I am not able to see the notification in the notification area for Pidgin chat. Not sure why.

When all Pidgin windows are closed it stays open I think but I am not always sure.

I used Kadu and it worked in the notification area, but I stopped using it because it kept crashing.

It's not a huge deal, but I have to keep the roster window open all the time... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [install Pidgin Indicator plugin](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/pidgin-indicator-ubuntu-appindicator.html) in Loki.

PPA installation instructions are provided at the linked address, but we can avoid the PPA by downloading the deb file from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pidgin-indicator/).

Once installed, open Pidgin and Tools > Plugins, then scroll down to "Ubuntu Indicator" and enable it.

[image]

[image]